# "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION' when creating a new ADO NET Model VS 2015

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to create a new ADO Model in Visual Studio 2015, using entity framework, connecting to a local MySQL Server
Currently Using:
EF 6.2.0, 
MySQL-connector 6.9.9
MySQL Server 8.0.11

After selecting DB and tables, I am getting this error:

Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the fix:

1. Updated the MySQL Connector Net to 6.10.8 (I has 6.9.9)
2. Changed MySQL for visual studio to 1.2.8 (I had 2.0.5). For some reason, 1.2.8 is the version is currently being recommended for install.
3. At Visual Studio 2015, Server Explorer, I deleted all Data Connections.
4. Upgraded all projects in my solution to use MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entity to version 6.10.8 (all they were on 6.9.9). Note: it is important that the version of those libraries MUST MATCH with the MySQL Connector Net (step 1).
5. When doing step 4, I got an issue with some of the projects inside my solution. Trying to update to 6.10.8, Nu-get printed the following error:

> ```
> Failed to add reference to 'System.ComponentModel'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
> ```

6. All I did (I found it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/issues/18)) was to add the following line to the .csprj file of each of the projects I got error:

`<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel" />`

Now it seems to work!

Happy hacking!
MT